# Creating a rpm package with make from PHP source

Tags: php, rpm

My project should have a spec file in its directory (hence it's not in the `SPECS` directory) which can be used to build a rpm package from the package with `make rpm`.

The project itself is a Symfony application. Hence when installing the package 3 things should happen:

- copy the application to its destination (preferably the proper apache2 directory)
- copy a configuration file to `/etc/appname/`
- create a directory for log files in `/var/log/appname`

The app can be built with `make dist`, which builds the app and creates a `dist.tar.gz` file afterwards.

As far as I've understood `rpmbuild` it should be enough to implement the `%install` section of my spec file. But my problem is that within this section I'm inside the `~/rpmbuild` directory, where neither my zipped app nor my source code lives. Simply `cd` to another dir wouldn't work, since I don't know where the spec file was called (and the rest of the project is).

What I want is something like this:

```
Name: appname
# rest of the header (group, summary, ...)

Source: dist.tar.gz

Requires: php >= 7.0, apache2

%description
important words

%install
cp * /var/www/appname # copy the application to its destination
cp docs/config/example /etc/appname/ # copy config to its destination
mkdir -p /var/log/appname # create log directory
```

Additionally, I'm not sure about what my `%files` should be in this case and about permissions.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Creating RPM Packages with Fedora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package), where you can see good description of each phase of rpmbuild (this understanding is useful even if you don't package for Fedora).

That said, the quick answer is: You would need a `%prep` section, where you would extract the source tarball via `%setpu -q` macro (the tarball is referenced in `Source: dist.tar.gz`). It seems that you can skip the `%build` section. In `%install` section, you need to create all directories you are going to need first, and then copy (install) all the files into it's proper place (you need to use `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` prefix in the destination path instead of absolute path you use in your example). And last but on least, in `%files` you need to list all the files you installed in the `%install` section which you want to be part of the rpm package.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, I'll try out later. One remaining question tho: listing all files in `%files` would be an insane long list (due to vendors). Is there a way to list all files recursively?

Comment: Yes, referencing the directory (where you copied some files in `%install`), is enough.

Comment: Prefixing my dest path with `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` results in a "directory not existent" error, since things like `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/var/www...` doesn't exist. Why do I have to use RPM_BUILD_ROOT then?

Comment: You need to use `RPM_BUILD_ROOT` because you *do not build RPMs as root*. What is located there will eventually be relative to the system's root once installed.